# Why is it that $\left|b_n - b \right| < \frac{\left|b \right|}{2} \Rightarrow \left| b_n \right| > \frac{\left|b \right|}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Unfortunately I am stuck on one step of a proof for an algebraic limit theorem, specifically:

Why is it exactly that $\left|b_n - b \right| < \frac{\left|b \right|}{2} \Rightarrow \left| b_n \right| > \frac{\left|b \right|}{2}$ ?

If this doesn't make sense without more context, please let me know. Otherwise, thank you for your help!

Comment: My recommendation is to first draw a picture of the number line :-). Make that two pictures: one with $b$ positive, and the other with $b$ negative. Where can $b_n$ lie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a version of the triangle inequality that says $\big| \,|x| - |y| \,\big| \leq |x - y|$ for all $x$ and $y$. So you have
$$\big|\,|b| - |b_n|\,\big| \leq |b - b_n| < {|b| \over 2}$$
So in particular you have
$$|b| - |b_n| < {|b| \over 2}$$
Rearranging this expression gives what you want.

Comment: @ghshtalt This version of triangle inequality is often called the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help! Part of what I overlooked is that $|b_n - b| = |b - b_n|$... I think I was trying to do this, but I kept getting $\frac{3|b|}{2}$ or something... Anyway, I think it makes sense to me finally :)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use $|x|\le|y|+|x-y|$ hence $|y|\ge |x|-|x-y|$ for suitable values of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

You may divide everything by $b$, then this is equivalent to the statement:
 $|x-1|\lt 1/2$ implies $x\gt1/2$.

In other words: if $x$ is at a distance less than $1/2$ from $1$ then $x$ must be greater than $1/2$.

Comment: Nice idea, but you should divide by $|b|$ and not $b$. (Also if I should nitpick, what if $b$ happens to be zero? :-))

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: Sure (and well...:)

Comment: If $b=0$ the implication is trivially true.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Sure but then it is just boring words flying around... :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the antecedent, we want to show $\frac{|b|}{2} > |b_n-b| \Rightarrow |b_n| > \frac{|b|}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{|b|}{2} \color{red}{+|b_n| - \frac{|b|}{2}} = \color{LimeGreen}{|b_n|} &> |b_n-b| \color{red}{+|b_n| - \frac{|b|}{2}} \\
&= |b-b_n| \color{red}{+|b_n| - \frac{|b|}{2}} \\
&\ge |b-b_n+b_n| - \frac{|b|}{2} \\
&= |b| - \frac{|b|}{2} \\
&= \color{LimeGreen}{\frac{|b|}{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: @Later Thanks, I have corrected it.